# Compare output of "DOS" command to something

Tags: batch-file, dos, windows-shell

(by DOS I mean windows cmd.exe - I don't want to enforce powershell or similar on the end user)

I want to run a command line file that prints output to CON / the screen.

I want to capture that output and compare it to an expected output.

... in a .bat / .cmd file?

---

Specifically, the [`identify` command of ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php), and I want to run this over +- 300 files and compare the actual sizes to expected sizes.

example output:

> $ identify rose.jpg
>
> rose.jpg JPEG 640x480 sRGB 87kb 0.050u 0:01

Comment: Do you mean file or image sizes (resolution)? In what form are the expected values provided?

Comment: @zb226 I was just looking to capture the text output of many commands, in a way I could compare it to some expected values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to run the identify command on all the jpg files in a directory and capture the output of that command into a text file for later comparison. The comparison however is not part of the spec?

Something like the line below should do that job. Just run it from the folder the jpg files are located:

for /R %%X in (*.jpg) do identify %%X >> PicInfo.txt
This will capture the rose.jpg JPEG ... line for every .jpg file you have in the directory (and subdirectories thanks to '/R') that you run the command in and append it to the file PicInfo.txt.

Comment: thx - comparison was not part of the spec because I have a few ways to do that (fc, comp and others). The trick I wanted was to get the output of the command into a single file, ready for comparison against an expected output. The combo of `for /R` and `>>` is the trick I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `identify` program with a symbol that redirects console output to a file, which is the `>` character. Something like:

```
identify rose.jpg > myoutput.txt
```

Additionally, the `>>` will append output to what is already in the file. So using

```
identify rose.jpg >> myoutput.txt
```

...should create one file with all your output.

You can then use the DOS COMP command, which compares the contents of two files. The syntax is:

```
COMP [data1] [data2] [/D] [/A] [/L] [/N=number] [/C] [/OFF[LINE]]
```

Which you could also redirect to an output file using the `>` symbol.